# Crystal Report WinForm How to Fix it Error Object reference not set to an instance of an object?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, compiler-errors, crystal-reports-2008

crystal report 2008 on WindowsForm C#

**Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

How to Fix it?

```
string appConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connDB"].ConnectionString;

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter dtAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt;
            string strSQL;

            strSQL = "SELECT * FROM filesTA WHERE ChkDate = '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";

            objConn.ConnectionString = appConn;
            var _with1 = objCmd;
            _with1.Connection = objConn;
            _with1.CommandText = strSQL;
            _with1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            dtAdapter.SelectCommand = objCmd;

            dtAdapter.Fill(ds, "myDataTable");
            dt = ds.Tables[0];

            dtAdapter = null;
            objConn.Close();
            objConn = null;

            ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
                   rpt.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Report\\CrystalReport1.rpt")); <<< Error
            rpt.SetDataSource(dt);
            this.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
            this.crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
        }
```

Help me please. Thanks you for you time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I would suggest looking at the stack trace closer. However, my guess would be that `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` is null. Many people do not realize that this can be null, so when you try to reference it's `Server` property you get a null reference exception.